# Откуда появилось число в результате умножения?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Метод вызывается в другом классе с параметром пути к файлу.gif размером **428х65**. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть метода - порезать каждую текстуру на квадраты размерами как я понимаю **32х32**.

Проблема: не понимаю что `getSubimage` проделывает второй раз в цикле.
`System.out.println` выводит итог первой "резки" и второй:

В первый раз понятно почему в конце стоит цифра ноль - это координата икс ведь 0*32+0=0:

```
subimage = tileset.getSubimage(0 * 32 + 0, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
System.out.println(subimage + " 1 range");
```

> BufferedImage@7f55097e: type = 13 IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8
>   numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@5eadcf0b
>   transparency = 2 transIndex   = 2 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false
>   ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 32 height = 32 #numDataElements 1
>   dataOff[0] = **0 1 range**

Но во второй цифра стала **14124**.

```
System.out.println(subimage + " 2 range");
```

> BufferedImage@2b83f3c1: type = 13 IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8
>   numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@5eadcf0b
>   transparency = 2 transIndex   = 2 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false
>   ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 32 height = 32 #numDataElements 1
>   dataOff[0] = **14124 2 range**

**Вопросы:** как я понял 14124 появилось в результате умножения 428(ширины гиф файла) на  нужный размер квадрата 33 (32 + 1). **Откуда взялись эти 14к?** **И что происходит во втором действии?**

**P.S.** на все следующие циклы в первом и втором действии прибавляется по 33. то есть уже не 0, а 33. не 14124, а 14157.

```
public void loadTiles(String s){

    try{
    tileset = ImageIO.read(new File(s));
    int numTilesAcross = (tileset.getWidth()+1) / (tileSize + 1);
    tiles = new Tile[2][numTilesAcross];

    BufferedImage subimage;

    for(int col = 0; col < numTilesAcross; col++){

        //в первый цикл col = 0. значит col * tileSize + col = 0. здесь понятно.
        subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize + col, 0, tileSize, tileSize);
        System.out.println(subimage + " 1 range");
        tiles[0][col] = new Tile(subimage, false);

        //col все еще равен нулю, но теперь col * tileSize + col = 14124
        subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize + col, tileSize +1, tileSize, tileSize);
        System.out.println(subimage + " 2 range");
        tiles[1][col] = new Tile(subimage, true);

    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: В выводе сказано: `dataOff[0] = 14124`. Что такое `dataOff[0]` и зачем это нужно - мне неизвестно, но с чего бы ему быть равным `col * tileSize + col`?

Comment: забыл еще один вопрос добавить: а что конкретно происходит во втором действии?

Comment: Об этом стоит спросить автора кода. Судя по названию метода, из набора картинок берётся конкретная с заданных Х и У и с заданными шириной и высотой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Различие вызвано тем, что при первом вызове в [`getSubImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) передается координата левого верхнего угла `y` равная 0, а при втором `tileSize +1`

```
subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize + col, 0, //... неважно
subimage = tileset.getSubimage(col * tileSize + col,  tileSize +1, //...
```

Соответственно, первый `subimage` — квадрат из верхней строки, а второй — из нижней.

> В первый раз понятно почему в конце стоит цифра ноль - это координата икс ведь 0*32+0=0

В выводе не указано, что это координата `x`, 14124 в данном случае значение внутреннего поля, которое выводит `BufferedImage.toString`.

Как видно, при преобразовании в строку `BufferedImage` выводит внутренний объект типа [`ByteInterleavedRaster`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/awt/image/ByteInterleavedRaster.java), тот в свою очередь выводит первый элемент внутреннего массива [`dataOffsets`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/awt/image/ByteComponentRaster.java#L60).

> BufferedImage@2b83f3c1: type = 13 IndexColorModel: #pixelBits = 8 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@5eadcf0b transparency = 2 transIndex = 2 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false **ByteInterleavedRaster**: width = 32 height = 32 #numDataElements 1 **dataOff[0] = 14124** 2 range

Судя по комментариям `dataOffsets` содержит сдвиг данных в байтах от начала файла для каждой строки вырезанного квадрата. `dataOff[0]`, соответственно, сдвиг первой строки.

Обратите внимание на то, что формат в котором `BufferedImage` преобразовывается в строку не описан в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#toString()) и, соответственно, является деталью реализации. Делать из строкового представления какие-либо выводы не стоит.

Comment: похоже на правду. спасибо за ответ.